# What does co_await operator actually do?

Tags: c++, async-await, c++-coroutine

I have searched the Internet trying to find what does the `co_await` operator do, but I still can't understand that. I guess that the following code:

```
co_await foo();
```

suspends the coroutine until `foo` is done, but in this case how it differs from simply calling `foo` like:

```
foo();
```

This will also suspend the current function until `foo` is done. Please, explain me.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://lewissbaker.github.io/2017/11/17/understanding-operator-co-await)?

Comment: Thank you! This article is quite difficult for me to follow. :( Could you please explain the concept in a simpler way?

Answer (score 12):

If function contains at least one `co_await` operator, the whole function is considered to be a coroutine. All its scope variables (including parameters) are stored on the heap, not on the stack. This makes it possible to suspend the function execution without losing its state and resume when needed. Also the coroutine returns control to the caller on the first suspend, and completes on the first `return` statement. Since it returns uncompleted, the return type must be an "awaitable type", such as `std::future<int>`. (C++ allows you to create your own awaitable types - and it's awesome!) The caller can subscribe/`co_await` on function completion.

Important to note that the suspended function may resume and complete at any time and on any thread; details depend on the implementation.

In your example, when you write `co_await foo()`, you will get to the next line only after `foo` completed execution and this line may be executed in another thread, however writing `foo()`, will get to the next line when `foo()` is only suspended in the same thread, and you won't have any feedback about its completion.